# What is a better way to get unique array Items based on key in PHP?

Tags: php, array

I'm trying to achieve a set of unique array with my following function.

### The Function:

```
/**
* uniqueAssocArray Removes arrys which have same keys
* @param  Array $array     Array to get unique items from
* @param  String $uniqueKey the unique key 
* @return Array            new array with unique items
* @author Junaid Qadir Baloch <shekhanzai.baloch@gmail.com>
*/

function uniqueAssocArray($array, $uniqueKey) {
  if (!is_array($array)) {
    return array();
  }
  $uniqueKeys = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if (!in_array($item[$uniqueKey], $uniqueKeys)) {
      $uniqueKeys[$item[$uniqueKey]] = $item;
    }
  }
  return $uniqueKeys;
}
```

### Example Array:

```
$actualArray = array(
    user1 => array(
        'name' => 'User1',
        'age' => '25',
        'lastLogin' => '2013-08-16'
    ),
    user1 => array(
        'name' => 'User1',
        'age' => '25',
        'lastLogin' => '2013-08-10'
    ),
    user2 => array(
        'name' => 'User2',
        'age' => '35',
        'lastLogin' => '2013-08-08'
    ),
    user1 => array(
        'name' => 'User1',
        'age' => '25',
        'lastLogin' => '2013-07-10'
    )
);
```

I then call the function like so:

```
$resultArray = uniqueAssocArray($actualArray, 'name');
```

### But...

I wonder is there a better way to do the same ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array is already sorted, you can just overwrite the values every time. Skip the inner if.

```
function uniqueAssocArray($array, $uniqueKey) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return array();
    }
    $uniqueKeys = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        $groupBy=$item[$uniqueKey];
        if (isset( $uniqueKeys[$groupBy]))
        {
            //compare $item with $uniqueKeys[$groupBy] and decide if you 
            //want to use the new item
            $replace= ... 
        }
        else
        {
            $replace=true;
        }
        if ($replace) $uniqueKeys[$groupBy] = $item;   
    }
    return $uniqueKeys;
}
```

Comment: Haha! i had already done the same but I have to accept your answer.
There's one catch though, Array must be sorted in reverse order. and I test for existence for a key before I replace the values blindly.

Comment: @mnhgI hope you won't mind if i un-accept your answer. I'm still looking for a better way

Comment: If you want the last element each, you need an ascending order. You are just overwriting the value again and again until you are on the last key.

Comment: Yes, but what if the array is random?

Comment: If performance doesn't matter, sort it. If you want to handle this in the same loop just compare the current items key value with the already inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use the function `array_unique`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

If you prefer to go with your own solution, have a look at the method `array_key_exists` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to replace your condition:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $uniqueKeys)) {
    $uniqueKeys[$item[$uniqueKey]] = $item;   
}
```

A bit off-topic here, but you probably don't want to store a user's age but rather her birthday, to make sure it stays up-to-date.

Comment: If I get him right he wants to use the last not the first duplicate each.